# function log2syslog in kali linux 2023.4

Tags: bash, kali-linux, logs, rsyslog

Can you please help me with this ? im trying to logging the bash commands. In Centos or another Linux OS works , but does not wotk in Kali Linux. I have created shell file with name `log2syslog.sh` in `/etc/profile.d` with the following syntax and does not work. Can you please help ? i have tried many many things.

```
function log2syslog {
   declare command
   command=$(fc -ln -0)
   logger -p local6.notice -t bash -i -- $USER : $SUDO_USER : $command
}

trap log2syslog DEBUG
```

Comment: It seems that you are trying to use Kali (from `https://www.kali.org`: __Kali Linux__ is an open-source, Debian-based Linux security distribution geared towards various information tasks, such as Penetration Testing, Security Research, Computer Forensics and Reverse Engineering. ) as a general purpose Linux system. This is unwise. Rather, install a supported Ubuntu release. You can build or install any of the Kali tools.

Comment: What do you mean by "_it doesn't work_"?

Comment: in the others LINUX OS like centos or linux mint , when you setup this script , you see logs in /var/log/syslog file. In kali you dont see these logs. I tried also to put this function to /etc/bash.bashcr or /etc/profile but without success.

Comment: Have you looked at the rsyslog config file(s) and enabled the service? The defaults for Kali might not be what you're expecting, particularly if you are comparing Kali to CentOS or some other user-friendly distribution. Please be aware that [Kali is not for everybody](https://www.kali.org/docs/introduction/should-i-use-kali-linux/).

Comment: I have checked all of these. And the rsyslog status and all. Im wondering if some have done the same in the kali linux

Answer (score 1):

`zsh` is the default shell on Kali Linux.

You can revert back to bash:

```
chsh -s /bin/bash
```